# Deploying issue with react,nodejs,express on production

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs

This is my first project using nodejs and react, I have been working a aplication by following this [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@Keithweaver_/building-a-log-in-system-for-a-mern-stack-39411e9513bd).Its working fine localhost

but not working on prodution mode.I have created a build and its generated a directory called "dist". I have moved everthing to live server from "Dist" folder.

But the node route not working , its says 404 error.How to deploy nodejs with react on production?

Can please help me get rid of it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you specified a static folder which directs to the uploaded `dist` folder?

Comment: @Bernhard, Yes i have specified. Frond end working fine with react. But backend node js only the problem. Here is the my server.js https://gist.github.com/gmangandan/1c171c523b4b92aad5b3cbc94289f41f file

Answer (score 0):

Your backend server will not know how to handle the routes on your client or know the location of your "client" folder, if you have a `dist` folder you would need to do something similar to this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('dist'));
  const path = require('path');
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
 });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried, but still same problem. I have misconfigured on live server i think. Totally i have confused with configuration on production. Here is my folder structure on live server https://ibb.co/iabfNe. Can you please advise me what i am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: You would need to post your code for the `server/index.js` and also `server.js`

Comment: Code here [index.js](https://gist.github.com/gmangandan/5e07c96d1f1b41cef87041631237262e) and [server.js](https://gist.github.com/gmangandan/1c171c523b4b92aad5b3cbc94289f41f)

Comment: How are you setting the `NODE_ENV` in your production version?